# Is there any way to dynamically choose which table's ORDER BY goes first?

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by

I am using SQL on DB2, on an IBM Power. I have a statement which pulls in the same data from multiple CTE's then orders by a few fields. But the thing is when there are nulls in either, how can I say 'if this is null, order by this other field that is the same thing instead'? I have a feeling this is impossible but I figure I would ask. I am trying to add multiple results into each row so I can save on performance for grabbing static info in one statement. Both of the pictures are in the same result.

Sorry I have to block off some of the data but I hope it helps.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGb3K.png]

Comment: sorry the second URL didn't work, https://imgur.com/PHVqQyL

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, please update your question instead of adding/changing information by commenting. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from mytable
order by coalesce(thisField, otherfield);
```

testing

```
SELECT * FROM CMW1
ORDER BY FLD1
```

Results

```
FLD1        FLD2 
ABC         ABC  
-           TEST 
-           ABC
```

With coalesce

```
SELECT * FROM CMW1           
ORDER BY coalesce(FLD1,fld2)
```

Results

```
FLD1        FLD2 
ABC         ABC  
-           ABC  
-           TEST
```

Comment: never knew you could do this! Thanks but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @AS4noob then your issue isn't as described. Likely `thisfield` isn't actually Null.

Comment: I am using an OUTER JOIN. If there is no data, the information that is missing is held with NULL placeholders, am I wrong?

Comment: @AS4noob nope, should be null if missing from the joined file... Edit your question and show what you are getting and what you want.